# overriding clone method but it is still protected

Tags: java, clone, overwrite

```
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
DoublyLinkedList<E> other=(DoublyLinkedList<E>) super.clone();
if(size > 0){
  other.header=new Node<>(null,null,null);
  other.trailer=new Node<>(null,other.header,null);
  other.header.setNext(other.trailer);
  Node<E> walk=header.getNext();
  Node<E> otherWalk=other.header;
  while (walk != trailer){
    Node<E> newest=new Node<> 
 (walk.getElement(),otherWalk,otherWalk.getNext());
    otherWalk.setNext(newest);
    walk=walk.getNext();
    otherWalk=otherWalk.getNext();
  }
  }
 return other;
 }
```

I overrided the clone method as public and used it in my code.

```
public Object deepCopy() {
Node<E> walk = header;
while (walk != trailer) {
  Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>((E)
          (walk.getElement()).clone(), null, null);
  ......
```

but it has an error that says "clone() has an protected access in java.lang.Object".

I have already changed the clone method as public in my class, why it is still protected ?

Comment: Don’t get it. Which class do you want to clone?

Answer (score 0):

When you try to invoke the clone method like you did:

```
(E)(walk.getElement()).clone()
```

it tries to invoke the `clone` method defined in the `Object` class and then tries to cast the clone to the `E` type. But it fails since the `Object#clone` method has protected scope.

In order to invoke the overridden `clone` method you have to write it like this:

```
(E)((E)(walk.getElement().clone()))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I don't understand that it is an object class method and my first and second code in the same class so my clone method is the last updated part. why does not it use? I think it is weird. Also can you explain twice casting at your second code? For example walk.getElement().clone() returns an object, why we should cast it two times?